# Filtering out values in specific columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter certain rows that contain a string instead of a float for 2 particular columns .

here is the header :

```
DATE,OPTION,SELL,BUY
```

This is how I group and write my data to split it out in smaller csv files per "option" :

```
grouped = df.groupby('OPTION')

for name, group in grouped:
    group.to_csv(name+'.csv')
```

The SELL and BUY columns contain mostly floats but in some rare instance they contain strings.
How can I filter these rows out in order to just write new csv without strings in the SELL and BUY columns ?

Thanks in advance,

---

**EDIT**

So far the answers didn't seem to get rid of the bad values, but I've got the feeling it could be because of the data itself ( containing numbers in the strings, here is a small sample of the actual data )

```
DATE,OPTION,SELL,BUY
2014-01-14 11:01:02.168146,Asx 200 [232],Asx 200 [112],47.7
2014-01-14 11:01:02.868105,Asx 200 [232],Asx 200 [112],47.8
2014-01-14 11:01:03.566983,Asx 200 [232],40.5,49.1
2014-01-14 11:01:04.279423,Asx 200 [232],40.5,49.0
```

I would like the output csv to just be :

```
DATE,OPTION,SELL,BUY
2014-01-14 11:01:03.566983,Asx 200 [232],40.5,49.1
2014-01-14 11:01:04.279423,Asx 200 [232],40.5,49.0
```

Since *Asx 200 [112]* is present in the SELL column .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no NaN is you data, you can use `convert_objects`:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [1.0, 2.0, "a", 3.0]
y = ["b", 5.0, 3.0, 7.0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x, "y":y})
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()
```

If there are NaNs in your data, use `applymap`:

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda x:isinstance(x, float)).all(1)
df[mask]
```

**EDIT**

For the sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

txt = """DATE,OPTION,SELL,BUY
2014-01-14 11:01:02.168146,Asx 200 [232],Asx 200 [112],47.7
2014-01-14 11:01:02.868105,Asx 200 [232],Asx 200 [112],47.8
2014-01-14 11:01:03.566983,Asx 200 [232],40.5,49.1
2014-01-14 11:01:04.279423,Asx 200 [232],40.5,49.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(txt))

df[["SELL","BUY"]] = df[["SELL","BUY"]].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df.dropna()
```

Comment: convert_objects looks interesting but I wasn't able to get rid of the problematic rows . I've edited the question

Comment: `df.dropna()` doesn't act in place-- maybe that's confusing the OP?

Answer (score 0):

An easier option is to convert the specific `Series` or the entire `DataFrame` to numeric.

#### Sample

```
In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,'c'], 'b':[2,3,4]})

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  c  4
```

Converting to numeric type

```
In [20]: df  = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
    a  b
0   1  2
1   2  3
2 NaN  4
```

Dropping NA

```
In [22]: df = df.dropna()

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
```

#### Reference

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html

Comment: The answer given by me, and HYRY work fine (as they should). Maybe you didn't do `df = df.dropna()` at final step?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there might be better solution, but the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
trade = pd.DataFrame({'BUY': [100.0, 'error', 200.0, 300.0], 'SELL': [50.0, 100.00, 'oops', 250.0]})
float_mask = trade.applymap(lambda x: type(x) == float)
trade[float_mask['BUY'] & float_mask['SELL'] ]
```

Here are how the data look like:

the outcome

```
     BUY     SELL
0    100     50
3    300     250
```

with the original input, trade:

```
     BUY     SELL
0    100     50
1    error   100
2    200     oops
3    300     250
```

Wish better solution to appear.